# What does the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra say about...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

1. the number of complex zeros of a polynomial function?

would it be safe to say it states the complex zeros of a polynomial function always come in pairs where they are conjugates of each other... or is there more to it than just that?

2. the number of linear factors of a polynomial?

would it be safe to say that it guarantees a polynomial of a degree $n\ge 1$ has the same amount of linear factors as its degree?

Comment: Does the polynomial have real coefficients? This is very important and you should have learnt this fact from your last question.

Answer (score 1):

1. The number of zeros (counting multiplicity) is the degree of the polynomial
   (except for the trivial case of the polynomial $0$).  For polynomials of degree $\ge 1$ the number of distinct zeros is at least $1$, and is at most the degree.

The non-real zeros only come in complex-conjugate pairs if the coefficients of the polynomial are real.

2. Yes, the number of linear factors is equal to the degree.

Comment: My first answer was incorrect?

Comment: Your first answer was not an answer to the question, and was incorrect.

Comment: Concerning question 1, aren't there exactly the amount of zeros (real and complex) as the degree of the polynomial?

Comment: That's what I said (counting multiplicity).  If you count only distinct zeros, then no.  For example, $x^2$ has degree $2$ and only one zero.

Comment: Remember that the real numbers are a subset of the complex numbers.  Counting complex zeros includes real-valued zeros.